# Calling functions on my SavingsAccount object and printing the result

Tags: java, function

I have a SavingsAccount object and I am trying to use my functions to manipulate the balance of the account. Now I get no errors but no output. I have the feeling that I have done something wrong and I don't quite understand how to call my functions on the object.

If I try to print the output for one of the accounts I make I get a memory adress.

I got all kinds of different errors while tweaking and its finally error free. But still no output and I am afraid I got it quite wrong and its just buggy and I don't call my functions the right way, or my constructor is not coded as its ment to be.

```java
public class SavingsAccount {
  // Class
  int balance;
  int amountToDeposit;
  int amountToWithdraw;

  //Constructor
  public SavingsAccount(int initialBalance, int deposit, int withdraw){
    balance = initialBalance;
    amountToDeposit = deposit;
    amountToWithdraw = withdraw;
  }

  //Functions thats I wanna call

  // Setting balance
    public void checkBalance() {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
        System.out.println("Your balance is " + balance);
    }

  // Depositing amounts 
    public void deposit(int amountToDeposit) {
        balance = balance + amountToDeposit;
        System.out.println("You just deposited" + amountToDeposit);
  }

  // Withdrawing amounts
    public int withdraw(int amountToWithdraw) {
        balance = balance - amountToWithdraw;
        System.out.println("You just withdrew" + amountToWithdraw);

      return amountToWithdraw;
  }


  // Main
  public static void main(String[] args){
    //Setting values, balance, deposit, withdraw.
    SavingsAccount savings = new SavingsAccount(2000, 100, 2000);
    SavingsAccount test = new SavingsAccount(5000, 200, 100);


    //Check balance
     System.out.println(test); // Will give a memory adress
  }       
}
```

I would like to use my functions on the object I make and print the result.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Think more carefully about your object model. Do the fields amountToDeposit and amountToWithdraw really belong to a SavingsAccount? No, they're just transient values that are just used as arguments to methods. Maybe, at best, they belong to a Transaction class. Also, your comment "Will give a memory address" is incorrect: it's not a memory address, but a hash value (printed in hexadecimal).

Comment: you should override the toString() method to print the SavingsObject properties.

Answer (score 0):

> I have the feeling that I have done something wrong and I don't quite
>   understand how to call my functions on the object.

You can call your methods with the variable name of a SavingsAccount, followed by a ".", and then the method you would like to call.

So, rather than

```
//Check balance
 System.out.println(test); // Will give a memory address
```

You can do this, for example:

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
    //Setting values, balance, deposit, withdraw.
    SavingsAccount savings = new SavingsAccount(2000, 100, 2000);
    SavingsAccount test = new SavingsAccount(5000, 200, 100);

    test.checkBalance();
  }
```

or

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //Setting values, balance, deposit, withdraw.
    SavingsAccount savings = new SavingsAccount(2000, 100, 2000);
    SavingsAccount test = new SavingsAccount(5000, 200, 100);

    test.deposit(50);
    test.checkBalance();
}
```

With that in mind, perhaps it makes more sense to only specify a starting balance when constructing a SavingsAccount. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can implement `toString` to print the object as below:

```
package com.stuart.livealert;

public class SavingsAccount {
    // Class
    int balance;
    int amountToDeposit;
    int amountToWithdraw;

    //Constructor
    public SavingsAccount(int initialBalance, int deposit, int withdraw){
        balance = initialBalance;
        amountToDeposit = deposit;
        amountToWithdraw = withdraw;
    }

    //Functions thats I wanna call

    // Setting balance
    public void checkBalance() {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
        System.out.println("Your balance is " + balance);
    }

    // Depositing amounts
    public void deposit(int amountToDeposit) {
        balance = balance + amountToDeposit;
        System.out.println("You just deposited" + amountToDeposit);
    }
    // Withdrawing amounts
    public int withdraw(int amountToWithdraw) {
        balance = balance - amountToWithdraw;
        System.out.println("You just withdrew" + amountToWithdraw);

        return amountToWithdraw;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{balance : " + balance + " deposit : " + amountToDeposit + " withdraw : " + amountToWithdraw + " }";
    }

    // Main
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Setting values, balance, deposit, withdraw.
        SavingsAccount savings = new SavingsAccount(2000, 100, 2000);
        SavingsAccount test = new SavingsAccount(5000, 200, 100);


        //Check balance
        System.out.println(test); // Will give {balance : 5000 deposit : 200 withdraw : 100 }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call your functions in the constructor:

```
public SavingsAccount(int initialBalance, int deposit, int withdraw){
    balance = initialBalance;
    deposit(deposit);
    withdraw(withdraw);
    checkBalance();
}
```

Then you will see all the System.out messages without the need to change the main method.